# How do I get the last consumed message offset of a Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose there is a topic A, and six messages are sent to it. Then, a consumer is attached to this topic to consume all the messages, and then disconnected. Using `fetchTopicOffsets` in KafkaJS, the offset would be 6, high would be 6, and low would be 0.

If six more messages are sent to this topic A and another consumer is attached to consume them, it would begin consuming messages from offset 6. However, using `fetchTopicOffsets`, the offset would be 12, high would be 12, and low would be 0.

Is it possible to determine the last consumed message offset in this Kafka topic? In this case, the last consumed message offset should be 5, as the messages with offsets 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 were consumed by the first consumer.

Comment: Removed tags. Answer will be the same with any Kafka client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without tracking the starting offset of each "batch" (minus 1) on your own.

Kafka consumer groups only persist where a new consumer instance should start from, not a history of each and every consumer execution. If there is no stored offset, it will use `auto.offset.reset` value.

If you waited approximately 7 days (topic retention time), then the "low" would be higher than `0`.